# JSDoc: how to describe variable as class constructor?

Tags: javascript, class, documentation, jsdoc

I assign class constructor function to my variable `clazz`. New instance `inst` is an instance of `SomeClass` and is described as `@type {SomeClass}` with JSDoc:

```js
class SomeClass {}

/** @type {???} */
const clazz = SomeClass;

/** @type {SomeClass} */
const inst = new clazz();
```

How can I describe `clazz` variable with JSDoc?

Answer (score 0):

IDEA understands this form: `@type {typeof SomeClass}`:

```js
class SomeClass {
    static NAME = 'name'
}

/** @type {typeof SomeClass} */
const clazz = SomeClass;

/** @type {SomeClass} */
const inst = new clazz();
const staticName = clazz.NAME; // IDEA autocomplete is available here
```